# Plugin view icon not displaying properly

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-plugin

I am stuck with this weird issue, where the icon of my custom plugin view is not getting displayed. However when the view is minimized, the icon can be viewed properly (see the screenshot, the icon is displayed properly in the minimized side bar).

[image]

All other image icons (in the toolbar) are getting displayed. Any pointers on what could be the issue.

All images are under 'icons' folder under the project, and the 'icons' folder has been added to the classpath.

See code snippet for the views from `plugin.xml` below:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
        <view class="com.ukris.review.view.ReviewTrackerView" icon="icons/reviewtracker_16.png" id="id.reviewTableView" name="Review Tracker"></view>
        <view class="com.ukris.review.view.ReviewEditorView" icon="icons/revieweditor_16.png" id="id.reviewEditorView" name="Review Editor"></view>
</extension>
```

Snippet from `build.properties`:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar,\
               icons/
```

---

**Edit**: 
When I restart the workspace, the icons become visible :o . But if I close the view again and then open, again the icon is missing :(. Also note the toolbar going up.

[image]

Comment: You say 'icon' folder in the text but have 'icons' in the extension point. The folder does not need to be in the classpath but does need to be in the build.properties.

Comment: That was a typo.. and the folder is in the `build.properties` too. question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the issue resolved by changing the id of the views in the *plugin.xml* file.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
        <view class="com.ukris.review.view.ReviewTrackerView" id="id.view.reviewTableView" icon="icons/reviewtracker_16.png"  name="Review Tracker"></view>
        <view class="com.ukris.review.view.ReviewEditorView" id="id.view.reviewEditorView" icon="icons/revieweditor_16.png"  name="Review Editor"></view>
</extension>
```

Not sure of the reason why this worked, but might be due to temporary files created in the plugin, which might be interfering with the current view.